# Busch Gardens Williamsburg VA without a car

Tags: public-transport, amusement-parks

I was thinking of taking my family to Busch Gardens and Water Country in Williamsburg VA. The issue is that we do not have a car or license. It looks like Amtrak has a couple of trains a day to [Williamsburg (WBG)](https://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am/am2Station/Station_Page&code=WBG) and [Amtrak](https://www.amtrak.com/virginia/busch-gardens-williamsburg) says we can hail a taxi from the station. My question is how easy is it to get to the parks, hotels, and food without a car? We are fine taking buses or spending money on taxis/Uber/Lyft/etc or shuttles. We just don't want to get trapped someplace, or not be able to get somewhere, because the bus isn't running and there are no taxis.

Comment: I believe that everywhere in the US, except very thinly populated areas, it's save to assume taxis are available. Bus service may vary in quality and frequency. For Williamsburg, Google "Williamsburg taxi" gives [this](https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=taxis&find_loc=Williamsburg%2C+VA).

Comment: Not sure what you are used to, but in suburban communities, it's more common to summon a taxi by phone, rather than waiting for one to pass by and hailing it.  So being "trapped" shouldn't be an issue as long as you have a phone - it just may take some time until your taxi arrives.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the nature of this destination, there are loads of public transportation options for Williamsburg and the surrounding area, and many hotels run shuttle services to attractions, including Busch Gardens and Water Country USA.

[Williamsburg Vacations](http://williamsburgvacations.com/williamsburg-transportation/) has a good overview (no affiliation) and, while it mentions one hotel with shuttle, check before booking your accommodation, as many others do, as well.

> When you plan to visit Williamsburg there are a number of transportation options to make it easy to get around during your stay. Most Williamsburg Hotels are located along the route of the Williamsburg Area Transit system, and others offer complimentary transportation to attractions including Busch Gardens and Water Country USA.
>
> **Williamsburg Area Transit System**
>   The Williamsburg Area Transit System runs between most hotels and all major Williamsburg Attractions. The fare is $1.25 per person each way plus $0.25 for a transfer between lines.  While the buses do have several stops along each route and it could take up to an hour to reach your destination, this is one of the most economical ways to travel in Williamsburg and each of Williamsburg’s Vacations‘ hotel partners has a stop within one block of the hotel.  Pay $10.00 for a weeklong pass good for unlimited rides for seven days.
>
> **Williamsburg Trolley**
>   The Trolley connects Williamsburg’s dining, shopping, and entertainment areas including Merchant’s Square, High Street and New Town.  For only $1.00 each way (per person) park in one location and leave the driving to us.
>
> **Historic Triangle Shuttle**
>   This free service is operated by Colonial Williamsburg and offers transportation between the Colonial Williamsburg Visitor Center, Jamestown and Yorktown beginning in March and running through November 3, 2012. The shuttle leaves the Visitor Center every half hour between 9:00AM and 5:00PM.
>
> **Colonial Williamsburg Shuttle Buses**
>   Ticketed guests of Colonial Williamsburg or anyone staying at a Colonial Williamsburg Hotel, including the Williamsburg Lodge and Williamsburg Woodlands Hotels may use the Colonial Williamsburg Shuttle Buses free of charge. The buses have numerous stops including the Historic Area, Merchant’s Square, the Visitor Center, Golden Horseshoe Golf Club and the Colonial Williamsburg Hotels.
>
> **Hotel Shuttles**
>   Guests of Kingsmill Resort, will enjoy complimentary transportation provided by their hotel to Busch Gardens, Colonial Williamsburg, Water Country USA, Jamestown and Yorktown.
>
> **Amtrak**
>   Amtrak trains that arrive at the Williamsburg Transportation Center service Williamsburg.  The Williamsburg Area Transit services this location or a private taxi may be arranged.
>
> **Taxi Services**
>   Williamsburg also offers a limited number of taxi services. Fares and schedules vary by company.
>
> **Airports**
>   The Newport News-Williamsburg International Airport (PHF) is the closest airport to Williamsburg and is approximately 15 miles away. In addition Norfolk International Airport is 45 miles east of Williamsburg and Richmond International Airport is 45 miles west of Williamsburg. Rental Cars are available at either airport or transportation from Richmond may be arranged through Groome Transportation at 800-552-7911.